# How to create bridged connections in Virtualbox (Windows 10)

Tags: virtualbox

I am trying to create a Linux virtual machine hosted in Windows 10 that has a unique IP address from the host. I understand that a bridged connection is required for this but can not find simple instructions for how to accomplish this.

When I change the network settings in Virtualbox to 'Bridged Adapter' and set the Promiscuous mode to 'allow all' the virtual machine cannot connect to the internet. I assume there is something in the Windows host that needs to be done but can not find what that is.

Comment: Don't messed with VirtualBox `Adapter 1` NAT settings. Keep this as-is. Now, you may tinker freely on `Adapter 2` with a bridge.